# null pointer exception on handler for utility class being called from main class. sockets program Android

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, handler

I made two classes,  the first is Server class that runs a thread to wait for and accept a socket connection from the client.

the second class is the EchoThread class that starts a new thread that gets the text message passed by the socket connection.  the reason for this is becase it is requied to do this so I can connect more than one client at a time to the server. so I created this class.  It is called in the while(true) loop in the Server class to start a new thread when a connection is made.

the problem is that the logcat for this app is a nullPointer exception for the EchoThread class, at this line:

```
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
```

why am I getting this error message and what to do about it?

Server class:

```
  public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus = "Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP;
                    }
                });
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true) {
                    // listen for incoming clients
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction("com.example.diceRolled");
                            intent.putExtra("serverStatus","Connected");
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }
                    });

                    new EchoThread(Server.this, client).start();

                } // end while(true) method  

            } else {  // the rest of the code for Server class....
```

EchoThread class:

```
 public class EchoThread extends Thread {
        protected Socket socket;
        private String line;
        private Handler handler;
        private Context context;
        private Socket client;

      public EchoThread(Context c, Socket clientSocket) {
                        this.socket = clientSocket;
                        this.context = c;
      }

      public void run(){
      try {
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

          while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
          //    Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
              handler.post(new Runnable() {
                  private String receivedCommand;

                @Override
              public void run() {
              receivedCommand = line;

              Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("com.example.diceRolled");
                intent.putExtra("serverStatus", line.trim());
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);


  Toast.makeText(context, "sent message " + receivedCommand, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  // the rest of the code for EchoThread class....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handler stays `null`, since you make it as a class variable

```
private Handler handler;
```

but then you never actually give it anything to hold.

When you come across

```
handler.post()
```

An NPE is thrown.

Therefore, you must instantiate `handler`, or give it a non-null reference to hold.

If you want more info about Handlers and Loopers, [this](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/) and [this](http://blog.xandroid.mobi/android-tutorial/tutorial-collection/loopers-and-handlers-in-android/) may be of value (same links as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7926914/1815485) SO answer.